# Possible to disable internal SSD on Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro

Is it possible to temporarily disable the SSD on a Macbook Air?

I want to [install XP on an external USB drive](http://guides.macrumors.com/Boot_Camp_Windows_XP_On_External_Drive) to work with my Late 2010 Macbook Air.  This technique requires detaching your hard disk in order to make the image.  That's obviously a problem since my disk is soldered onto my motherboard.. but on the same token I imagine there's a way to disable it (what if there was an actual malfunction?  perhaps it just renders the unit useless but I'd hope not).

I have a MBP I can do this on, but XP will surely NOT like to be transferred from one machine to another..

Comment: Get a Windows XP USB edition and copy it to your USB!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSD is *not* soldered to the motherboard, it just has a new, unique connector. You can get in there and detach it. Check iFixit for instructions, and beware that such may void your warranty.

And if the Pro is recent enough, it may indeed work to install on there and transfer to the Air.

Comment: That's right, it's the RAM that's soldered.  Good thinking